# Delayed evaluation of functions in InputAutoReplacements and InputAliases

Tags: front-end, options, customization

The code

`CreateDocument[{},InputAutoReplacements->{"test"->DateString[]}];`

generates a new notebook and "test" triggers an output containing the timestamp pertaining the evaluation moment of the `CreateDocument` function. I want, instead, get any time an updated timestamp, so I childishly tried

`CreateDocument[{},InputAutoReplacements->{"test":>DateString[]}];`

but unsuccessfully because an error is raised:

> An unknown box name (DateString) was sent as the BoxForm for the expression. Check the format rules for the expression.

By the way, `InputAliases` exhibits the same behaviour.

Any hint would be very appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Not giving any guarantees but try with:

```
SetOptions[
  EvaluationNotebook[]
, InputAutoReplacements -> {
    "test" -> ToBoxes @ Dynamic[DateString[], DestroyAfterEvaluation -> True]
  }
]
```

Comment: If no quotes should be shown one might do `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 InputAutoReplacements -> {"test" -> ToBoxes[Style[Dynamic[DateString[], DestroyAfterEvaluation -> True], "Text", ShowStringCharacters -> False]]}]`

Comment: @RolfMertig this adds StyleBox to the cell structure so I'd go with `Dynamic[DateString[], DestroyAfterEvaluation -> True]`, depends what's OP need.